# Wordpress: using a test theme only for a specific user

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm testing a new template for a wordpress based site, and I'd like to test it directly on the live version instead of making copies. I thought I could create a test user (wordpress is bridged with vbulletin which handles user auth), serve the usual theme to anyone BUT that specific user, who would get the new testing one.

I don't want to install a plugin, I'm looking for the right place to edit to insert this check:

```
if logged user == test_user_id
    serve 'testtheme'
else
    serve 'normaltheme'
```

The userid can be get from `$_COOKIE`.
I tried hacking the `get_template()` function in `wp-include/theme.php` but apparently that was not enough. Any suggestion?

Comment: As a side note, this should be helpful to all wordpress theme designers: http://devideas.blogetery.com/testing-wordpress-themes-easily/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best way to "test" or develop a theme behind the scenes *without* needing to alter too much of your Wordpress core or make custom changes...

http://digwp.com/2009/12/develop-themes-behind-the-scenes/

Comment: Nice article, seems like the best solution. Will try asap, thanks

Comment: No problem! Let me know if it does it for you. ;)

Comment: [theme test drive](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-test-drive/) works perfectly, it's just what I needed thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Just logging into my old Wordpress.com blog, I see that I can do all the previewing I want from the themes manager already - click around to any page I like, or bring up the frame's URL to see what query string I'd have to append to a URL to get the same preview, e.g.

```
?preview=1&template=pub/mytheme&stylesheet=pub/mytheme
```

Any reason that's not enough?

Comment: I need to show it to people who don't (and can't) have admin access

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should add a column to your user table, call it "is_beta" and if it's set to 1 then enable beta features/themes.  This way you can easily add or remove people from the beta, and when you're beta is ready to launch, you flush the column for everybody and make the features default.